# Creating a parameterized Operator in Qiskit that cannot be decomposed into Qiskit supported gates

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, hamiltonian-simulation, vqe

I am trying to create a custom ansatz to use the built-in Qiskit VQE() function. My ansatz is composed of single qubit gates and a hamiltonian gate which cannot be decomposed into  Qiskit supported gates. Here is my ansatz function:

```
def quantum_state_preparation(sites, reps):
qc = QuantumCircuit(sites)
num_params = reps*(2*sites+1)
params = ParameterVector('θ', num_params)  

H = 0*SparsePauliOp('I'*(sites))
for j in range(1, sites):
    H -= 1/2 * (SparsePauliOp('I'*(j-1) + 'XX' + 'I'*(sites-j-1)) + SparsePauliOp('I'*(j-1) + 'YY' + 'I'*(sites-j-1)))
ham_op = H.simplify()

for n in range(reps):
    ham_gate = HamiltonianGate(ham_op, params[n*(2*sites+1)]/2)
    qc.append(ham_gate, range(sites))

    for i in range(sites): #single qubit gates
        qc.p(params[n*(2*sites+1)+1+2*i] ,i)
        qc.rx(params[n*(2*sites+1)+2+2*i] ,i)
qc.parameter_bounds=[[0,2*np.pi]]*num_params 
return qc
```

When I plug quantum_state_preparation(sites, reps) into the VQE() function it fails. I am pretty sure it is because HamiltonianGate() is unable to handle unbound parameters but I don't know a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [HamiltonianGate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.extensions.HamiltonianGate.html) docs `...which can be decomposed into basis gates if it is 2 qubits or less, or simulated directly in Aer for more qubits.`

Try [PauliEvolutionGate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PauliEvolutionGate.html) which is what the [EvolvedOperatorAnsatz](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.EvolvedOperatorAnsatz.html) in the circuit library uses and is the base class for QAOAAnsatz there and UCC in Nature and they work with VQE.